# How to setup python to use at Terminal in PyCharm

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I am running PyCharm on a server without administrative acess.
The server has Python 2.7 installed.

I am using Anaconda3 Python 3.5.3 when running programs and in the Console.
However, I cannot find where to set the Terminal of PyCharm to the same Python (Anaconda3/Python 3.5.3)

It keeps using the 2.7 and I cannot delete it from the server.
Thanks.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up the path to the correct python binaries, when  you add the remote interpreter in PyCharm:

[image]

Write there the path to your anaconda installation. So in your case the Python interpreter path is something like:
 /your_install_path/anaconda/bin/python3

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find such option.

Comment: When I setup 'Python Interpreter' it is ok and Python runs on 3.5. It is only the Terminal access that I don't know where to indicate the correct path. There is no word 'remote' in PyCharm

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-remote-python-interpreters.html

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, I will have look.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know where your problem is. After setting up the correct interpreter, for me it's working fine. Even if I start python console or terminal from PyCharm. Or do you mean how to do it from a terminal window?

Comment: You should also know, that this option is only available in the professional edition but not in the CE.

Comment: Thanks, In the past I have seen this option Add Remote, but in my current version of PyCharm 4.5.1 there isn't such an option. In my own computer, the Terminal runs the same version of Console, but not in the server. I know I have to include PYTHONPATH or something like that somewhere, but not exactly. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, I use community. But anyway, I should be able to configure the correct version of Python for the Terminal, right?

Comment: That'S for sure, that should be independent from PyCharm. :-) I don't know if you've already tried the simplest way, to run with python3 command instead of just python. If both are installed sometimes that helps. What kind of system is it?

Comment: 'not recognized'. Windows Server

Comment: Was just an idea... I work usually with linux systems so I don't really know what you have to do. Let's see if somebody can help you with that.